# protobuf ShortDebugString() has a poor performance when dealing with \0(null)

Tags: protocol-buffers

I generated a file in the following way：

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=20M.file bs=1M count=20
```

I use the tool to read the file and send it to my server.

The server use ShortDebugString() to print the message. However, I found that it takes a lot of time. If I process the same size of normal data, it will be much smaller. why?

Comment: It's a guess, but is it trying to process 20M null strings? Instead of, presumably, a much smaller number of non-null ones.

Comment: processed the same size, both are 20M.

Comment: If they are the same size, then presumably the 20MB of non-null strings is a much smaller number of strings? The point I was making is that maybe the overall time to execute is dependent on the number of calls to ShortDebugString() rather than the size of the message.

Comment: The 20MB message is one request, call ShortDebugString() only once. Null strings and non-null strings call ShortDebugString() the same number of times